# Merge two images with transparency in imagemagick

Tags: images, imagemagick, merge, transparency, montage

I have two images without transparency (two photos) and I want to combine these images into one image where first image covers second image. How to scale these images to the same size and merge with transparency like in example below?

[image: example result]

Comment: You might read this page: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#compose

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Imagemagick* is a complex tool with a lot of options.
In the example you posted it seems that to the first image is superimposed (overlapped) a copy flipped with some transparency level. All actions that you can do at the price of a complicate *commandline*.

Let's suppose, for sake of simplicity, that you have just ready the two images. Give it a look to <sup>[[1](http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26606)],[[2](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/tables/)]</sup> to understand better how it works. In the second reference <sup>[[2](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/tables/)]</sup> you can have a guess by examples about the methods available in *Imagemagick* to *add two images*.

Probably the `-dissolve` <sup>[[3](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#dissolve)]</sup> or the `-blend` <sup>[[4](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#blend)]</sup> option is what you are searching for:

```
composite -dissolve 50 -gravity Center a.jpg b.jpg -alpha Set result.jpg
```

Another way to do it can be <sup>[[5](http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26606)]</sup>

```
convert FUfstEv.jpg  \
\( ChYNTch.jpg -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 50% +channel \) \
-gravity center -compose over -composite result1.jpg
```

Additional operation may have to be added to scale the image if needed...
As additional reference you can see <sup>[[n](http://www.svgopen.org/2005/papers/abstractsvgopen/)]</sup>. See again this page <sup>[[5](http://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=26606)]</sup> for some examples.

In general the syntax of the `dissolve` option can be similar to the following one:

> composite -dissolve {argument}  -gravity Center \
>               1.gif   2.gif -alpha Set   {result}